# Creating App With 50 US states checkbox in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am pretty new to RoR and I am trying to create an app on which users can multiselect states (checkboxes) and have the selections saved (think "what states have I been" to type of thing).  In creating a Class that has these as attributes, what is the best way to approach the scaffold and to get them to display?  I figure putting all 50 states in the Scaffold probably isn't the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You could have an array column in your model where you store the id's of the states, but that is not a good solution.

The best solution I would say is to create an intermediate table (since one state can be checked by multiple users and a user can check multiple states) with a model associated to it:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :state_check
  has_many :states, through: :state_checks
end

class StateCheck < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :state
end

class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :state_check
  has_many :users, through: :state_checks
end
```

This way you can do something like:

```
@user.states
```

And eventually you can add more stuff to the relation in the state_check table.

You probably should read: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association